# Visualise midi file with midiConvert and Tonejs

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to visualise a `midi` file using `react.js`, `midiConvert` and `tone.js`.

I think there is a problem with the import; I have this error:

```
Uncaught Bad .mid file - header not found
```

I have tested the `midi` file and it is ok. I try `midiconvert` with `node` and `express` to see if there is something, but nothing is in the object.

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Tone from 'tone';
import * as Pixi from 'pixi.js';
import * as MidiConvert from 'midiconvert'

// Pixi.js
var width = 800
var height = 600
var scale = 50
var keyboard = 100
var app = new  Pixi.Application(width, height, {backgroundColor: 0x222222})
document.body.appendChild(app.view)

var graphics = new Pixi.Graphics()
graphics.beginFill(0xffffff)

var line = new Pixi.Graphics()
line.beginFill(0xff0000, .5)
line.drawRect(0, 0, width, keyboard)

app.stage.addChild(graphics)
app.stage.addChild(line)

// Tone.js
var synth = new Tone.PolySynth(8, Tone.Synth, {
    oscillator: {
        type: "sine3"
    },
    envelope: {
        attack: .03,
        decay: .1,
        sustain: .2,
        release: .6
    }
}).toMaster()

function playNote(time, event) {
    synth.triggerAttackRelease(event.name, event.duration, time, event.velocity)
}

MidiConvert.load('./zelda.mid').then(function(midi) {
    console.log(midi)
    Tone.Transport.bpm.value = midi.bpm
    Tone.Transport.timeSignature = midi.timeSignature
    midi.tracks.forEach(function(track) {
        var w = width / 127
        track.notes.forEach(function(note) {
            var x = (note.midi / 127) * width
            var y = keyboard + note.time * scale
            var h = note.duration * scale
            graphics.drawRect(x, y, w, h)
        })
        new Tone.Part(playNote, track.notes).start(0)
    })

    Tone.Transport.start()
})

function update() {
    requestAnimationFrame(update)
    graphics.y = -Tone.Transport.seconds * scale
  }

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      hee
       {update()}
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

The file might be okay but it is possible that the react dev server (or another server) is not serving the correct file from the URL. It is possible that the server is just returning an HTML in its place.

- Look into the Network tab in the browser dev tools.
- Locate the midi file in the list
- Right-click and try to open the file using the link.

Comment: Thank a I'm new in the dev world. I did what you say. And I think you are right because there is this message : "you need to enable JavaScript to run this app"

Comment: I don't how can I use it

Answer (score 0):

I try this just to get a look :

```
class App extends Component {
```

render() {
    return (
      
        {MidiConvert.load('./zelda.mid',function(midi) {

```
        console.log(midi)

        Tone.Transport.bpm.value = midi.bpm
        Tone.Transport.timeSignature = midi.timeSignature

        midi.tracks.forEach(function(track) {
            var w = width / 127
            track.notes.forEach(function(note) {
                var x = (note.midi / 127) * width
                var y = keyboard + note.time * scale
                var h = note.duration * scale
                graphics.drawRect(x, y, w, h)
            })
            new Tone.Part(playNote, track.notes).start(0)
        })

        Tone.Transport.start()
    })}
   {update()}
    <p className="App-intro">
      To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
    </p>
  </div>
);
```

}
}

but there is this error :

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
in div (at App.js:58)
in App (at index.js:7)
at invariant (invariant.js:42)
at throwOnInvalidObjectType (react-dom.development.js:11898)
at createChild (react-dom.development.js:12109)
at reconcileChildrenArray (react-dom.development.js:12341)
at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:12655)
at reconcileChildrenAtExpirationTime (react-dom.development.js:13015)
at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:13006)
at updateHostComponent (react-dom.development.js:13340)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:13828)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:15863)
at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:15902)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:100)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:138)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:187)
at replayUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:15310)
at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:15962)
at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:16560)
at performWork (react-dom.development.js:16482)
at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:16454)
at requestWork (react-dom.development.js:16354)
at scheduleWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:16218)
at scheduleRootUpdate (react-dom.development.js:16785)
at updateContainerAtExpirationTime (react-dom.development.js:16812)
at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:16839)
at ReactRoot../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js.ReactRoot.render (react-dom.development.js:17122)
at react-dom.development.js:17262
at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:16679)
at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:17258)
at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:17317)
at Object../src/index.js (index.js:7)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 650f6cadcfbff24b1408:678)
at fn (bootstrap 650f6cadcfbff24b1408:88)
at Object.0 (registerServiceWorker.js:117)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 650f6cadcfbff24b1408:678)
at ./node_modules/ansi-regex/index.js.module.exports (bootstrap 650f6cadcfbff24b1408:724)
at bootstrap 650f6cadcfbff24b1408:724
```